# PHP/MYSQL -Need help sorting array alphabetically

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I need the below codes to list venue names alphabetically in ascending order (A-Z).  Right now it's sorting the venues by when they were listed in the database. Where do I tweak?

```
     <?php for($ii = 1; $ii <= 10; $ii++): ?>
    <div class="bor_t menu_option_container"<?php if($ii != 1): ?> style="display: none;"<?php endif; ?>>
    <div class="mb20">
    <label class="ros_head alt_label" for="venue_option<?php echo $ii; ?>_note_field">VENUE OPTION <?php echo $ii; ?></label>
       <?php
            $venue_room_options = array();
            $venue_room_options["null"] = "Select a venue";

                            foreach($rooms as $room) {
                                $venue_room_options[$room->VenueID . '_' . 
                                $room->RoomID] = $room->VenueName . " - " . $room->RoomName;

                            }

                            echo form_dropdown('venue_selection' . $ii, $venue_room_options, ( set_value('venue_selection' . $ii) ) ? set_value('venue_selection' . $ii) : '1', 'id=""', array("id"=>"venue_option" . $ii));
                        ?>
                    </div> <!-- /.mb20 -->`
```

Comment: did you try `sort($arr)`??

Comment: Where is the array coming from? Database? Why don't you build it already sorted? It will be much faster than dealing with php array manipulation function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to maintain keys association, use the function asort like

```
<?php
...
asort($venue_room_options);
echo form_dropdown('venue_selection' . $ii, $venue_room_options, ( set_value('venue_selection' . $ii) ) ? set_value('venue_selection' . $ii) : '1', 'id=""', array("id"=>"venue_option" . $ii));
...
?>
```

There are a lot of PHP functions to work with array sorting:
http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the array by using php array function asort().

add sort function here

```
<?php 
// your code 

 asort($venue_room_options);  // new line added
 echo form_dropdown('venue_selection' . $ii, $venue_room_options, ( set_value('venue_selection' . $ii) ) ? set_value('venue_selection' . $ii) : '1', 'id=""', array("id"=>"venue_option" . $ii));

 ....
?>
```

This will sort by venueName-roomName  alphabetically

Answer (score 1):

Right above your foreach loop, insert the following code:

```
sort($rooms);
```

For more information, please refer to: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php